# Python's input() does not automatically recognize GNU readline

Tags: python, linux, readline

The first problem I had was Python's `input()` does not handle backspaces, and shows `^H` instead:

```
$ python3 -c "input()"
^H^H^H^H^H^H^H
```

However backspaces work fine in an interactive shell. Further investigation revealed that doing `import readline` makes it recognize backspaces.

```
$ python3 -c "import readline; input()"
# Backspace processed correctly
```

Thus I concluded that the problem that backspaces did not work can be reduced to a problem more closer to the root where GNU readline was not invoked automatically. I think Python's `input()` is supposed to handle backspaces without manually `import`ing `readline` as the source code of CPython suggests that (`Python/bltinmodule.c`):

```c
static PyObject *
builtin_input_impl(PyObject *module, PyObject *prompt)
{
    ...
    /* If we're interactive, use (GNU) readline */
    if (tty) {
```

How can I make Python automatically recognize `readline` installed on the system?

Update:

As pointed out in the comments, it's likely a problem of my environment. Most likely it is because readline is not installed correctly or something. This is a Debian server connected via ssh, and `stty -a` prints:

```
$ stty -a
...
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D ...
```

Therefore `stty erase ^H` would gets backspace working, but in a wrong way, I think, because other features of readline such as up arrow key to refer to the history, would still be unavailable. And also it would still remain unclear why backspaces work in other occasions such as bash or Python REPL shell.

Comment: The first version works fine for me on both Linux and Mac.

Comment: For me as well on Mac OS. Maybe depends on your shell version or env variables when it can't recognize tty for you for example

Comment: this is an enviroment issue rather than a python issue. you can set your backspace char so be what ever you like in linux, by default in most of the production servers i work on backspace is `CTRL+h` and using the actual backspace key. you can change that with `stty erase <key>`

Comment: Do you have a property TTY?  I noticed that when i am doing some work, the difference between a proper TTY and input may be inhibiting.